# Excel Treeview Creation VBA

Tags: html, excel, treeview, vba

I'm interested to know if it's possible to take a use selection of data and create a tree view out of it, formatted for HTML. Basically I have a excel worksheet with the following format.

[Excel Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7wCT.png)
And I'm looking to have it formatted as a tree view like the following

I have the code to create the treeview, however it's going to be a very large tree and manually typing this code to generate the tree will take forever and chances are I will be repeating this. Any suggestions?

**Edit** 
 
I think I may have been a little confusing, so let me be a little more specific. I've got a list of manual pages, each page is nested under 1-6 nodes. Currently I have the name of the page and what nodes they are nested under in an excel spreadsheet. My goal is to list these pages in a treeview. [View Image of Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i0D9.png). I'm trying to use VBA to create the nodes automatically, so that i don't have to sort through the nodes and type them all out myself. I hope that helps.

Comment: That is a Dot Net Treeview. Do you want it in Excel-VBA or Dot net?

Comment: Can't you just use the VBA-provided tree view? http://www.homeandlearn.org/introduction_to_treeviews.html

Comment: Treeview control is not an inbuilt VBA control. It is a VB6 control which can be accessed when you set a reference to `mscomctl.ocx`. And if you are planning to distribute the workbook then using it is a bad idea as the user may not have "mscomctl.ocx"

Comment: [Interesting Read](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/treeview.asp)

Comment: I guess it would be useful to clarify that I'd basically like my final format to be in html code, for each new node, it would create a node, and nest other nodes beneath that. <asp:TreeNode Text="Node_1" Value="Node_1" ></asp:TreeNode>

Comment: Then why Excel-VBA?

Comment: For an HTML solution usable in VBA please add extra tags.  Trying tagging with HTML, JQuery.  You'll need to create an instance of Internet Explorer to display the solution.